# Output from an array in html page

Tags: html, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am trying to output the contents of an array within an array to a small area on an HTML page. I can only get one dimensional arrays to output.

Simplified, the intended array has a number of properties, but am struggling to find the correct code to output an array nested inside an array.

Properties are;
ID(integer)
Location(string)
Postcode(String) 
other properties may be added down the line.

To output the information I am using the following code (which I can only get to work on a single array - even if I change to using [i][x] )

`document.write("<tr><td>ID " + i + " is:</td>");`

`document.write("<td>" + LocationArray[i] + "</td></tr>");`

How do I correctly create an array capable of storing the information and then output a specific part of it? eg display the contents of LocationArray[2][3]

Is document.write an efficient method, or is there something better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I put something together, that could help you. To answer your question at the end about creating an array 'the right way'; There are two possibilities:

- Create an array with 'property'-based properties : 
  `var locationsArray = [{ID:123,Location:'blabla',Postalcode:'1234'}];`
- Create an array with string-keys : 
  `var locationsArray = [{'ID':123,'Location':'blabla','Postalcode':'1234'}];`

In my example I used the first attempt.

To your second question: **document.write** just writes at the end of the document. If you want to write to a specific area of the website, create a container (for example) and give it an **id**. Then change the property **innerHTML** of the created container, as I did in my example.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="locations"></div>
<button onclick="printLocations()">Print Locations</button>
```

**Javascript:**

```
function printLocations() {
  var locationsArray = [{
    ID : 123,
    Location : 'Candyland',
    Postalcode : '1234'
  }, {
    ID : 456,
    Location : 'Middle-Earth',
    Postalcode : '4567'
  } 
  ];

  var locationsHtml = '';
  for (var index in locationsArray) {
        locationsHtml += 'ID: ' + locationsArray[index].ID + ', ' +
                         'Location: ' + locationsArray[index].Location + ', ' +
                         'Postalcode: ' + locationsArray[index].Postalcode + '<br />';
  }
  console.log(locationsHtml);
  document.getElementById('locations').innerHTML = locationsHtml;
}
```

If you just want to write a specific part of the array (in your example just one specific location) just use the index you want and access it the same way as in the for loop in my example:

```
  var locationsHtml = locationsArray[1].ID + locationsArray[1].Location + etc...; 
  /*with string-keys: var locationsHtml = locationsArray[1]['ID'] + etc...;*/
  document.getElementById('locations').innerHTML = locationsHtml;
```